# Is there Markdown support on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, markdown

Do the Stack Exchange sites support Markdown?

If so, what features do they implement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes, it does.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

> How to Format
>
> ► put returns between paragraphs
> ► indent code by 4 spaces
> ► for linebreak add 2 spaces at end
> ► backtick escapes `` `like _so_` ``
> ► blockquote using > at start of line
> `<http://foo.com>`
> `[foo](http://foo.com)`
> `<a href="http://foo.com">foo</a>`
> ► basic HTML also allowed