# Is there Markdown support on Area 51 sites?

Tags: support, area-51, markdown, stack-exchange, comments

Do the Stack Exchange sites on Area 51 support Markdown?

If so, what features do they implement?

Is there an example comment which shows some or all of the implementations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there Markdown support?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53437/is-there-markdown-support)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Italics via * [works](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1908/physics/2210#2210) and I think I've also seen bold ** and links

Comment: thanks - links did work for me as well (http URIs get auto-linked) but I was wondering how to create a line-break. Haven't tested italics and bold so far, but will do so.

Comment: according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/stack-overflow-comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks comments can't have line-breaks